# Meaning of 'take away'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I worked very hard. So I thought I could **take the afternoon away** simply because I deserved the break.

What is the exact meaning of 'take away' related to the context that the sentence might be in? (I can easily guess the meaning of the whole sentences but still curious about the exact meaning.)

Comment: I think the speaker meant *take sth off*? I've never heard *take sth away* used in that meaning.

Comment: Source of the quote please.  It looks like an error (should be "off")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic expression is "take the afternoon off", which means "take a break", which means "not work".

You shouldn't exactly substitute "away" for "off". It looks like an error.

However, you could form a sentence with "away from".

An example:

> take some time away from the job

Comment: Thank you. Now it makes sense!